# D3 version 5 custom x axis values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get custom x axis values in d3 v5 and most of the examples I can find online appear to be for previous versions and I can't make much sense of the docs right now...

I am making a bar chart from an object like this...

```
const data = {
  one: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
  two: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
  three: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
  four: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
}
```

so I want the x axis value of the bar chart to be the strings `one, two, ...`

my d3 code looks like this for the scales and axes

```
const keys = Object.keys(data);

let dataMax: number = 0;
keys.forEach(k => {
  if (data[k] > dataMax) {
    dataMax = data[k];
  }
});

const xScale = scaleLinear() // set the x scale and fit to width
  .domain([0, keys.length])
  .range([0, width]);

const yScale = scaleLinear()
  .domain([dataMax || 0, 0])
  .range([0, height]);

const s = select(this.node).select('.innerG');

s.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'xAxis') // set the class for the x axis
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(axisBottom(xScale)); // add the axis

s.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'yAxis') // set the class for the y axis
  .call(axisLeft(yScale)); // set the axis
```

and with this, my chart renders great but I get `1, 2, ...` for the x axis instead of my data keys which are strings. Most of the examples I find online say to use `tickFormat()` or `svg.axis()` but this appears to be older versions of D3. How can I do that with the current v5?

Comment: You should not use a linear scale for the bars' positions, that makes no sense I'm afraid (in a bar chart the position of the bars, the width of the bars and even their gaps carry **no information**). Instead of that, you have to use a **band scale**. However, such answer would change your code beyond the scope of the question, so I'll leave it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks thats what I was missing. If you can make it as an answer. I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to write yourself the answer , or just delete the question.